# Django model.objects.all does not show information

Tags: python, sql-server, django, visual-studio-code, ssms

I am using django to make a webapp and I am trying to learn how to make queries.

I already connected my SQLServer database to django, and from the SQL Management studio added information for the 3 tables that I have. Then I ran `python manage.py inspectdb`, copied the results in my `blog.models.py`and put `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `migrate`

However, when I open the python shell via `python manage.py shell`, import the models and make a `model.objects.all(), the result is the following:

```
<QuerySet [<Usuario: Usuario object (1)>, <Usuario: Usuario object (2)>]>
```

Django identifies that I have 2 objects created, but whenever I try to get specific information from one of them it shows the following:

```
>>> Usuario.objects.all()
   <QuerySet [<Usuario: Usuario object (1)>, <Usuario: Usuario object (2)>]>
>>> user= Usuario.objects.all()
>>> user[0]
   <Usuario: Usuario object (1)>
>>> user[0].ID_Usuario
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
   AttributeError: 'Usuario' object has no attribute 'ID_Usuario'
>>>
```

This is the information that I inserted via SQL Management studio

```
INSERT INTO Usuario(ID_Usuario,Nombre,Apellido,Edad,Email,Password,ID_Cargo,ID_Rol)
     VALUES(1,'Pepe','Arana',36,'pepe@hotmail.com','pass',1,1),
     (2,'Roquito','Velarde',40,'roquito@hotmail.com','pass',2,1)
```

Why isn't django recognizing the attributes but it is recognizing the fact that an object has been created?

Thanks

EDIT: This are the models in the blog.model.py file

```py
class Cargo(models.Model):
     id_cargo = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID_Cargo', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     nombre = models.CharField(db_column='Nombre', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     descripcion = models.CharField(db_column='Descripcion', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

     class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'Cargo'


 class Rol(models.Model):
     id_rol = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID_Rol', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     nombre = models.CharField(db_column='Nombre', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     descripcion = models.CharField(db_column='Descripcion', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

     class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'Rol'


 class Usuario(models.Model):
     id_usuario = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID_Usuario', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     nombre = models.CharField(db_column='Nombre', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     apellido = models.CharField(db_column='Apellido', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     edad = models.IntegerField(db_column='Edad', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     email = models.CharField(db_column='Email', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     password = models.CharField(db_column='Password', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     id_cargo = models.ForeignKey(Cargo, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ID_Cargo', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
     id_rol = models.ForeignKey(Rol, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ID_Rol', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

     class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'Usuario'
```

Comment: Please share your `Usuario` model. Likely the database name is not the same as the field name.

Comment: Ok, Give me a minute

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for the help, I think I know what´s the problema

Comment: the name of the column is `id_usuario`, not `ID_Usario`.

Comment: There also a tip if you might want to use is that you can implement __str__ method of your model to make your model more readable when querying in the shell.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, the problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

```
user[0].ID_Usuario
```

You are getting an error because `ID_Usario` is not defined in the models. `ID_Usario` is an only a column name in the database.

But in the model, you have defined as `id_usuario`.

Replace this with

```
user[0].id_usuario
```